# O que fazer com respostas ruins?

Tags: debate, respostas

Recentemente na fila de publicações de baixa qualidade, notei muitas respostas curtas e diretas, pouco explicativas, mas no entanto, respondiam a pergunta.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383855/realizar-chamada-%C3%A0-m%C3%A9todo-em-java/383861#383861) por exemplo, é objetiva e direta, não dá exemplos e outras informações, mas apareceu na fila de análise. O que fiz foi deixar como estava, pois afinal respondia a pergunta. Não sei se responde a pergunta, não entendo de Java.

Imagine o cenário que, o usuário faz uma pergunta enorme, detalhada e específica, e recebe uma resposta de três linhas, errada e sem nenhum código ou exemplo.

### Mas o que é uma resposta ruim?

O que você considera uma resposta ruim? Eu considero uma resposta que *deixa um vazio no ar*, sem exemplos, sem documentação, sem explicação, e que acima de tudo, **não responde a pergunta**. Algumas são tão "ruins" que poluem a publicação e não são a ponto de nem de ser compreendidas.

Mas, de qualquer jeito, continua sendo uma resposta válida a pergunta.

A respeito destas respostas, o que devemos fazer a respeito das mesmas?

---

*Quando uso o termo "errada", me refiro que a resposta não responde a pergunta, ou ao menos não ajuda.*

Comment: Tenho visto várias desse genero ultimamente, com 1-2 linhas de algo que é mais uma dica que resposta, mas que por vezes acerta no problema.

Comment: @Isac respostas enigmaticas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa é minha opinião, não sei se é o que a comunidade em geral pensa

Se a pergunta é realmente uma tentativa de responder, mesmo que ruim e não resolva o problema, **não** deve ser fechada

Agora se é um comentário de algum outro usuário com baixa reputação e que, portanto, não pode comentar ou reposta só com links ou qualquer outro motivo das opções de sinalização deve ser fechada

Mesmo que ruim uma resposta é uma resposta, pode não resolver o problema, mas de repente ajuda indiretamente o perguntador ou outra pessoa futuramente

Mas o que fazer?

É pra isso que serve a negativação, o ideal é que fosse acompanhada com uma breve explicação do motivo, incentivando o usuário a melhorar sua resposta e reverter a pontuação. Criticar é bom, mas deve ser construtivo, pode linkar alguma pergunta do meta ou da central de ajuda que explique o por que daquilo para não ter que ficar explicando em comentários

Answer (score 2):

Além de negativar, podemos explicar no comentário que a resposta não ajudou ou que falta informação... O que dá mais trabalho, eu sei...

Comment: Não tem haver com a sua questão, mas o pior ainda é **negativarem** a pergunta e nem se darem o trabalho de responder, mesmo quando a pergunta está bem explicada.