# Respostas vs Comentários na análise

Tags: debate, respostas, comentários, respostas-erradas

Eventualmente (maioria das vezes) na fila de **publicações de baixa qualidade** surge algumas respostas bem ruins mas que de certa forma **são respostas**, e muitas vezes são marcadas para serem transformadas em comentários.

Estamos confundindo comentários com [respostas ruins](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7777/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-ruins). E eu acho que isso está errado pelo fato de não deixarem de serem respostas. Desde que estejam erradas ou "ruins", **não deixam de ser respostas.** O que fazemos (pelo menos eu) quando vejo uma resposta ruim ou errada, negativo ela e comento indicando o que está errado/o que pode melhorar.

Exemplo: imagine o cenário onde pergunto: *como eu formato um número para exibir dois decimais em C#?*

E recebo a seguinte resposta:

> Use: `numero.ToString("N2")`

Esta resposta provavelmente será marcada como "Deveria ser um comentário", igual ocorre em algumas vezes onde já observei:

- [Como formatar data por extenso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/245162)
- [Problemas com font-face CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/243961)
- [Como fazer um balanceamento de classes em um problema de regressão em machine learning com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/239798)
- [Pegar Nome da Taxonomia de acordo com o slug - Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/244602)

---

Isso também se enquadra no [*Respostas em comentários*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7663/respostas-em-coment%c3%a1rios0), mas ao contrário. São respostas que pedimos que transformem-as em comentários.

Se estiver errado, então devemos passar a considerar respostas ruins e erradas como comentários? Se sim, me corrijam da minha conclusão com detalhes acerca, por favor.

Comment: A segunda que citou, Validar CEI, você acha que é uma resposta? Parece-me mais um trecho de código aleatório sem conexão com a pergunta. Veja que a pergunta nem é uma pergunta, é apenas uma publicação para compartilhar o código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem razão, não tinha observado isso na pergunta. Vou remover dos exemplos.

Comment: Na primeira, eu entendi que o autor da resposta estava fazendo uma pergunta exploratória pois o formato não se adéqua a requisitado na pergunta. Mas se realmente era uma resposta o erro é meu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De fato existe muito isto. Eu nego sinalizações como "não resposta" o tempo todo. Em geral a pessoa perdeu uma boa oportunidade de sinalizar como "baixa qualidade" porque é isso que é. Uma resposta sim, do jeito que a gente espera, mas está bem ruim.

Ser curta não quer dizer nada sobre a qualidade. Dizer nada com nada, basicamente só ter um *link* para a resposta, ser só uma opinião sobre o assunto e não responder nada, ser uma pergunta para o AP clarificar alguma coisa, ser *spam* claro, vandalismo, ser outra pergunta, ou uma tentativa de edição, ou alguma coisa do tipo é uma postagem que não pode ser classificada com resposta.

Ser uma resposta fraca, errada, curta, que tem um *link* complementar, que seja de outra linguagem, que desvia do assunto por si só não invalida como resposta. Resposta ruim merece negativo não ser apagada (eu até acho que poderia ser diferente por tanta coisa ruim que existe :) mas a filosofia do site não é essa e não podemos fazer do jeito que queremos).

Alguns casos não são fáceis de definir, porque é tão fraco que precisamos perguntar para o AR qual era a intenção dele postando aquilo. Na dúvida eu prefiro deixar, provavelmente negativando porque me deixou confuso, imagino alguém mais incauto. De qualquer forma olhe todo o contexto.

Comment: E o que fazemos com elas? Isso vai de cada usuário para usuário ou devemos adotar um padrão de respostas que deviam ser comentários?

Comment: O que está sinalizado errado, rejeita. Se der e for pertinente sinalize com o motivo correto, em geral de baixa qualidade.

Comment: Mesmo a VLQ é bastante subjetiva.

Comment: Toda a gente devia ler isto [When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/218708) e isto [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/218708)