# Deve existir na Central de Ajuda informações aos usuários sobre nossas restrições a respeito de conteúdo gerado por IA?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-revisão, central-de-ajuda, inteligencia-artificial

Devemos ou não incluir na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help) uma página informando ao usuário sobre as restrições impostas ao conteúdo gerado por Modelos Linguísticos Amplos(LLM) comumente apelidados de Inteligência Artificial?

##### Vote na pergunta para participar da enquete

- positivo para **SIM**
  devemos ter o tópico na central de ajuda
- negativo para **NÃO**
  não devemos ter o tópico na central de ajuda

---

Na [Central de Ajuda do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) podemos encontrar um tópico sobre o assunto que pode ser acessado por aqui:

- [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

<sup>OBS: O link [Política temporária: IA generativa (ex. ChatGPT) está banida. - *tradução direta*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) leva a uma regra publicada no respectivo [Site Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), o debate aqui proposto visa unicamente a Central de Ajuda.</sup>

Segue abaixo uma tradução livre para o português do texto [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).

> ## Por que não posso usar ferramentas de Inteligência Artificial para gerar respostas?
>
> Ferramentas de Inteligência Artificial (também
> conhecidas como GPT, LLM, IA generativa, genAI) não podem ser usadas
> para gerar respostas para o Stack Overflow. As respostas que você
> fornecer devem ser de seu próprio trabalho original ou de trabalhos
> devidamente [citados de terceiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Se for determinado que suas
> respostas foram escritas por uma IA, elas [provavelmente serão excluídas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage),
> junto com qualquer reputação obtida com elas. Publicar conteúdo gerado
> por IA repetidamente pode levar a um aviso dos moderadores ou até
> mesmo à suspensão do site.
>
> ### O que conta como uma “resposta gerada por ferramentas de Inteligência Artificial”?
>
> Uma “resposta gerada por ferramentas de Inteligência
> Artificial” é qualquer resposta elaborada parcial ou totalmente usando
> uma ferramenta que escreve uma resposta automaticamente com base em um
> prompt fornecido. Essas ferramentas incluem grandes modelos de
> linguagem como GPT e Bard. Como essas ferramentas são treinadas para
> responder com uma linguagem que corresponda ao texto autêntico, as
> respostas podem parecer plausíveis, mas a qualidade das respostas
> geradas pode variar significativamente (até, e inclusive, respostas
> completamente erradas).
>
> Alguns exemplos de serviços de IA comumente usados ​​para escrever
> respostas infratoras no Stack Overflow incluem:
>
> - GPT (também conhecido como ChatGPT)
> - Bard (LaMDA) Bate-papo do Bing
> - LLaMA
>
> Não redija respostas para Stack Overflow usando GPT ou
> outros serviços de modelo de linguagem grande (LLM) como os listados
> aqui.
>
> ### Por que não estou autorizado a utilizar serviços de Inteligência Artificial para redigir a minha resposta?
>
> Stack Exchange é um recurso colaborativo, desenvolvido e mantido por membros da
> comunidade. Existem alguns problemas principais com o conteúdo gerado
> por grandes modelos de linguagem que o tornam inadequado para uso no
> Stack Exchange:
>
> 1. Os usuários que fazem perguntas no Stack Overflow esperam receber uma
>    resposta cujo autoria e curadoria sejam de um ser humano. Isso garante que a
>    resposta seja factual, relevante e completa, de acordo com os padrões
>    de outro ser humano. Embora os autores humanos não sejam perfeitos, a
>    Inteligência Artificial pode não considerar outros fatores
>    importantes para uma pergunta (ou seja, optimização, segurança, etc.),
>    muitas vezes adicionar ruído excessivo às suas respostas (ou seja,
>    explicar todos os detalhes, independente da relevância), e pode
>    fabricar informações falsas ou enganosas.
> 2. Os usuários que fazem perguntas no Stack Overflow podem já ter procurado respostas em outro lugar. Pela facilidade de utilização dos serviços de Inteligência
>    Artificial, se um usuário desejasse uma resposta de uma Inteligência
>    Artificial, pode-se presumir que já a teria procurado. Se eles não
>    queriam uma resposta de uma Inteligência Artificial, não faz sentido
>    fornecê-la aqui.
> 3. As IAs não são capazes de citar as fontes de
>    conhecimento utilizadas [de acordo com os padrões da rede Stack Exchange](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Mesmo quando a Inteligência Artificial parece citar fontes
>    para as respostas, tais fontes podem não ser relevantes para o pedido
>    original ou podem nem existir. Para Stack Overflow, isso significa que
>    a resposta pode não representar de forma honesta ou justa as fontes de
>    conhecimento utilizadas, mesmo que alguém cite explicitamente a
>    Inteligência Artificial como autor em sua resposta.
>
> ### Existem alternativas ao uso de serviços de Inteligência Artificial?
>
> Muitas das respostas no Stack Overflow são criadas por usuários que
> compartilham seus próprios conhecimentos, embora isso não seja
> obrigatório. Em particular, ao fornecer respostas fora da sua área de
> conhecimento, os usuários devem citar fontes confiáveis. Buscar
> fontes, sintetizá-las em uma boa resposta e citá-las claramente são
> etapas críticas no desenvolvimento de uma resposta bem elaborada.
>
> Lembre-se: a pessoa que fez a pergunta precisa de uma resposta **correta**.
> Por isso, responder corretamente é sempre mais importante do que
> responder rapidamente, além disso, nosso sistema prospera em perguntas
> que obtêm múltiplas respostas boas, que têm maior probabilidade de
> ajudar futuros visitantes que tenham a mesma pergunta. Seguindo um
> processo que cria respostas consistentemente corretas e de boa
> qualidade e que são bem citadas conforme necessário, você se sairá bem
> aqui.

Eu pessoalmente sou favorável a inclusão do tópico em nossa Central de Ajuda pois:

- As informações são relevantes.
- Agrega valor a Central de Ajuda.
- Estar dentro da Central de Ajuda facilita o acesso a essas informações.
- O conteúdo não fica disperso, ou no nosso META ou outra Central de Ajuda que não seja do Stack Overflow em português.
- Traz informações relevantes para a língua portuguesa.

Lembrando que aqui no [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) possuímos dois debates sobre o uso de IA no site principal:

- [Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842/137387)
- [Como identificar conteúdo gerado por IA?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8853/137387)

Portanto, se for participar da discussão sobre a central de ajuda, utilize o campo de comentários ou resposta conforme o caso, mas se for discutir o mérito de permitir ou não AI, não é neste post. Idealmente deve fazer na postagem original sobre a proibição.

Comment: Se as pessoas lessem a Central de Ajuda, não haveria uma grande quantidade de conteúdo ruim por aqui (não apenas gerado por IA), então, não acho que fará muita diferença

Comment: @Costamilam concordo. não é adicionando mais uma página em um lugar fantasma que vai resolver o problema das IAs.

Comment: Considerando que o post já teve mais de 150 visitas, apesar de nem tantos votos,  estou repondo a tag de revisão. Dos que votaram, a diferença é suficiente para afirmar a tendência , e os textos já estão prontos no post abaixo. E este passo é necessário para [esta outra proposta aqui](/q/8912/) - aliás, pessoalmente não vejo sentido em ficar 'represando' documentação da plataforma para algo já decidido anteriormente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edição, 6 de dezembro de 2023:

Hoje vejo uma real necessidade de existir uma página curta dedicada à essa atenção em específico. Como [já tenho sugerido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8912/lembrete-que-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-respostas-geradas-por-ia) um lembrete, ele necessita de uma página para apontar e explicar a decisão da comunidade.

Inicialmente era contra, mas vejo que no geral os novatos não seguem nossos conselhos individuais e indicam perseguição. Espero que um termo oficial dessa recusa diminua um pouco essa sensação indesejada.

---

Eu não concordo que devemos deixar explícito que aceitamos somente respostas escritas por humanos [porque já está explícito isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Todo conteúdo gerado por LLM é... **gerado, não escrito**.

O que concordo que deveríamos enfatizar é que **não aceitamos respostas geradas ou copiadas** e puxar um gancho para exemplificar que IA é resposta gerada. Também pontuar que queremos respostas que o AP de fato escreva, pesquise e formule.

Não estamos impedindo ninguém de usar IA. Estamos impedindo de usar diretamente o conteúdo da IA no nosso site. [Aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede) explicam todos os motivos pelo quais a comunidade tomou essa decisão. Você é livre para perguntar para IA sobre alguma pergunta específica e com base no que ela disse você formular a sua própria e original resposta.

Destarte, [respostas ruins ainda são respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7777/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-ruins) e estão sujeitas ao julgamento e análise da comunidade. Todas as respostas geradas por IA são ruins, mas ainda é difícil saber se a resposta é de fato gerada por LLM. Alguns padrões e comportamentos do usuário acabam entregando um pouco o uso dela, mas por mais que não seja exato, ainda se categorizam como ruins e conteúdo ruim não é bem-vindo na comunidade.

Comment: Não seria esse o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing mais adequado para contextualizar a postagem?

Comment: @Abóbora também. O link que coloquei enfatiza que devemos escrever as nossas próprias respostas, o que interpreto que não envolve copiar algo de outra autoria, seja ela gerada ou não.

Comment: Concordo, é preferível enfatizar que o conteúdo deve ser criado pelo usuário (mesmo que baseado em outros conteúdos), assim, vale para qualquer caso, como cópia integral e talvez outros no futuro. Também poderia aproveitar e sugerir que o usuário forneça fontes quando houver e, em caso de cópia de parte de outro conteúdo, especificar (por exemplo, já copiei exemplos da MDN para respostas que criei)